# How to use autocomplete jQuery for different column fields?

Tags: jquery

In the Textbox field while creating writing some text say a task, user can enter like this

> This is a new task in #ST for £Sunil.

Then system has to capture the program ST and developer Sunil by searching database, in short I have to apply multiple autocomplete in a single textbox

I am trying this by jQuery but unable to do this for multiple fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery UI autocomplete having two different sources of data one for program another for developers and binding **keyup** event changing source according to requirement. Something like this sample from Jquery UI Autocomplete : [Multiple value autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)

Comment: I think this is not what Mona wants.
Mona: I don't think this feature is available with jquery or jqueryUi.

Comment: juzerali u r rite ...I want something like capturing event....like u can say google serach.....Please suggest me if any soln u hv?